# how to print tags or id in tkinter used in python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am using tkinter to generate a gui.

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("explorer")
f=Canvas(root, width=1200, height=768)
f.grid()
main_line = f.create_line(200,300,300,300, tags="main_line_tag", width=5)
mainloop()
```

in the above sample i want to print tag and id beside the line. how can i do it.

**Update**

```
main_line = f.create_line(200,300,300,300, tags="main_line_tag", width=5)
tags_text = ', '.join(f.gettags(main_line))
line_text = "%s: %s" % (main_line, tags_text)
f.create_text(220,320, text=line_text)
```

solution working but my actual requirement is

```
f=Canvas(root, width=1200, height=768)
f.grid()
class Create:
      def __init__(self,xy,t):
          self.xy=self.xy
          self.t=t
          for i in range(1, self.t+1):
              exec 'main_line%d = f.create_line(200,300,300,300, tags="main_line_tag%d")' %(i,i)
    #end of class Create
def update(t,newxy):
    for i in range(1,t+1):
         exec'f.coord(main_line%d, *newxy)'%i
mainloop()
```

in the above sample code iam trying to update coordinates of the line when i run the code i am getting main_line1 not defined.. even for tags also. how to resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: If you're using `exec`, you're doing it wrong. Why do you need to use exec to create variables for each line? Is there a reason you aren't just saving the line id in a list or dictionary? eg: `main_line[i] = f.create_line(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just draw a text item, and use the ID and the [`gettags`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.gettags-method) Canvas method to create your text.

```
main_line = f.create_line(200,300,300,300, tags="main_line_tag", width=5)
tags_text = ', '.join(f.gettags(main_line))
line_text = "%s: %s" % (main_line, tags_text)
f.create_text(220,320, text=line_text)
```

**Update**

The problem with `exec 'main_line%d = ...` is that you are creating the line, but not storing the reference. However, using `exec` is a non recommendable solution and there are another ways to do the same as you want with a simple list:

```
lines = []
def update(t, newxy):
    for line in lines:
        f.coord(line, *newxy)

class Create:
    def __init__(self, xy, t):
        self.xy = xy
        self.t = t
        for i in xrange(self.t):
            new_line = f.create_line(200,300,300,300, tags="main_line_tag%d" % (i+1))
            lines.append(new_line)
```

Comment: how can i bind these tags with tag_bind for all with out using exec method

Comment: @lokesh `for id_line in lines: f.tag_bind(id_line,...)` should work, but new questions are out of the scope of this one. If you have more doubts you should ask them in a separate post.